# how retrieve the last portion of the url using regex or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a url

```
/stars/planets/usa/en/universe/planet_stars.html
```

I need to get the `planets_stars.html`. How do I get that last portion alone?

Comment: find last index of ('/')

Comment: or .. use this: `/([^\/]+)$/`

Comment: `str.substr(str.lastindexof('/'));` something like this

Comment: Will you ever have to deal with URLs with query parts or fragment IDs? They make things quite a lot more complex…

Comment: @DoGood every time you are asking something, you should be polite and accept answers(vote up, i think and put green tick to this answer (under vote arrows))

Comment: @Kaf great comment! Maybe we should make a motivating poster with green tick?

Answer (score 1):

Neither jQuery nor regex necessary here:

```
url.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: using of LastIndex + SubStr will be more elegant in this task.

Comment: That seems rather subjective. I think brevity of code is nice, and this approach reads nicely to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript:

```
var url = "/stars/planets/usa/en/universe/planet_stars.html";
var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

**Edit:** second parameter of substring method optional and not required in this case. So, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

or just JavaScript.

```
var parts = url.split('/');

var lastpart = parts[parts.length -1];
```

You can use pop() as jmar said too, just remember that removes it from the array when you do it, so you can't use the pop method twice on the same array and get the same value.